# How to remove animation of maximizing/minimizing windows in Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-interface, aero

Since today, and maybe due to the latest Windows update, my system has an animation which slowly maximize (or minimize) the window until it completes (takes like 3 secs or a bit more on my machine).

I searched in the panel control, but cannot find an option to disable that effect.

Comment: I'd be more worried about why it's started doing it, than how to  turn it off. It's more likely the result of another problem, and you're just masking it. :(

Comment: As long as I didn't detect spyware or other kind of malware (and having the antiviruse updated) I prefer not to worry so much. This is not the first strange things happen after a win update.

Answer (score 9):

Found!

Go to

```
Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Performance
```

then uncheck `Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing`.

Comment: That's about the correct translation.

Comment: Ridiculous... that silly animation causes my music to stutter (despite the music program running at high priority) every time, on a high-end system. Heads should roll for that sort of thing.